# Will Ubuntu One Mobile be available on BlackBerry?

Tags: ubuntu-one, blackberry

Are there any plans to bring UbuntuOne Mobile to BlackBerry?

Answer (score 4):

It is not.
We are focusing on Android and iOS platforms exclusively in the mobile arena for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 2):

The UbuntuOne [webpage](https://one.ubuntu.com/mobile/) claims  that it support Blackberry contacts syncing.  Is this what you are after?

Use the phone finder option on the web-page to see  if you Blackberry model is supported, and to what level.