# Can I synchronise my BlackBerry 9700 Bold with Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, blackberry

Can I synchronise my BlackBerry 9700 Bold with Ubuntu One?

Comment: "This site is slightly pedantic and someone will have to re-take Coding 101." !?

Comment: and yes it is possible... start with mounting the blackberry as mass storage.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there are no plans to make a Blackberry client for Ubuntu One. If you really want to use Ubuntu One on your Blackberry device, you can use the [Ubuntu One website](http://one.ubuntu.com/) using your Blackberry Web browser.

Or you can use other [Ubuntu One alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/ubuntu-one/?platform=blackberry) for Blackberry.

---

References:

- [Will Ubuntu One Mobile be available on BlackBerry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39082/will-ubuntu-one-mobile-be-available-on-blackberry)
- [Can you make Ubuntu One Blackberry-compatible please?](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+question/165985)